# Second screen detection

Tags: nvidia, twinview

When I plug in my a second monitor on my laptop (sony vaio with Nvidia GT330M and proprietary driver) I have to log out and back in for the external screen to display something.

Is this really necessary? What are my other options? Why is the second screen not activated as soon as I plug it in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to logout.

1. Go to `System` → `Administration` → `NVIDIA X Server Settings` or click on the Applications lens in the Launcher and search for `NVIDIA`.

   [image: applications-lens-search]
2. Select `X Server Display Configuration`.

   [image: nvidia-x-display-settings]
3. From the `Model` drop down list select the display you want to activate.

   [image: nvidia-x-display-settings-model]
4. Click on `Configure` and select the option you need.

   [image: nvidia-x-display-settings-model-configuration]

Comment: So it's Nvidia's fault if this is not automatic?

Comment: I didn't state that. I can't tell you why it is not automatic, I guess because there are more options one can configure it and it is up to the user to decide what he needs.

Comment: Great, thank you. Just curious that they didn't think that I would like something displayed on the screen I just plugged in.