# Can't use external monitor via HDMI

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, external-monitor

I have an external monitor that is connected to my laptop via HDMI. I just upgraded to Natty and I can no longer redirect my video output to it using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. How can I get my external monitor working again?

- Hardware is a Dell XPS m1530.

It seems that I can twiddle with the nvidia settings and get configuration I am looking for, so I guess the real question is:

How can I get <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to switch my video out between monitors like it used to?

Comment: Can you had some hardware information to your question?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

That should help you if you have a nvidia graphics-card: 
[Second screen detection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37269/second-screen-detection/37274#37274)